# file access blocked by a lock - how to remove?

Tags: files, lock

I am trying to run the "check" function of backup program "restic" on one of the backup repositories it's created. No matter what I do, it crashes due to a fatal "already locked" problem. Here is the relevant command-line I/O:

```
tomc@ANB:~/programs/restic-backup$ ./restic check -r
/media/tomc/usbhd4-p2/_restic-bkup/dropbox using temporary cache in /tmp/restic-check-cache-405001323 
enter password for repository:
repository fd5c0b03 opened successfully, password is correct 
created new cache in /tmp/restic-check-cache-405001323 
create exclusive lock for repository 
Fatal: unable to create lock in backend: repository is already locked by PID 30546 on ANB by tomc (UID 1000, GID 1000) 
lock was created at 2019-10-07 14:49:41 (509h0m19.239359465s ago) storage ID 0fe63838
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
repository is already locked by PID 30546 on ANB by tomc
```

You should first use `ps -fp 30546` to see if the process that locked the repository still exists. Since the lock is already 509h old according to the error message, the process might be hung, or it might be a stale lockfile if the process does not exist or seems completely unrelated.

If the process with PID 30546 seems related, you might use `lsof -p 30546` to see which files it has open. With luck, one of those files might be a log file that might provide more information about the state of the process. If it seems safe to interrupt, you could use `kill 30546` to try and stop it relatively nicely, allowing it a chance to clean up its lock file as it exits.

If the process refuses to die with the `kill 30546` command, you could use `kill -9 30546` to force it to stop, but in that case, you will definitely have to take further steps to clear the lock.

According to [issue #1450 in the GitHub page of `restic`](https://github.com/restic/restic/issues/1450), after killing the hung process, you might use this command to clear the stale lock:

```
./restic unlock -r /media/tomc/usbhd4-p2/_restic-bkup/dropbox
```

If the hung process was in the middle of some backup operation, you might need to perform these commands too:

```
./restic check -r /media/tomc/usbhd4-p2/_restic-bkup/dropbox 

# if the check returns "not referenced in any index" errors, then do this:
./restic rebuild-index -r /media/tomc/usbhd4-p2/_restic-bkup/dropbox 
./restic check -r /media/tomc/usbhd4-p2/_restic-bkup/dropbox 

# if there is still "not referenced in any index" errors, remove incomplete packs:
./restic prune -r /media/tomc/usbhd4-p2/_restic-bkup/dropbox 
./restic check -r /media/tomc/usbhd4-p2/_restic-bkup/dropbox
```

After this, the check should pass without errors.

Comment: A variant worked:

./restic unlock --remove-all -r  /media/tomc/usbhd4-p2/_restic-bkup/dropbox

The --remove-all flag was needed because the lock happened as a result of my killing a previous restic process, and thus was not a mere "stale lock".

Thanks you for your exceptionally clear and detailed response. It far exceeded my expectations.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is somewhat Linux specific, but the concept holds in any POSIX system:

First figure out which process is actually *holding* the lock, typically this is the process that is *not* blocked by the lock.  This will list the processes holding the file open:

```
lsof /path/to/lockfile
```

Then get the file descriptor and unlock it:

```
# ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd
[... make a note of the file descriptor you care about and substitute <fd> below]
# gdb -p <pid>
gdb> call flock(<fd>, 8)
```

Above, `8` is `LOCK_UN` from `file.h`

If `flock` doesn't work then you could also try closing the file descriptor but that could introduce side-effects and the program may abort depending on how it was written:

```
gdb> call close(<fd>)
```

When you're done with `gdb` then let the program continue with `detach`:

```
gdb> detach
```

Comment: How do you find the lockfile path?

Comment: @FotisK, `ls -l /proc/<pid>/fd` will reveal it because the file descriptor must be open to hold the lock.  If it does not show up there, then you're most likely _not_ hitting an flock issue.